# Why does list.reverse() method return "None"?

Tags: python

```
cars = ["audi", "bmw", "ford", "tesla"]
print(cars.reverse())
```

The result is `None`.

```
newList=list(reverse_iterator)
print("reversed list is:",newList)
```

But when I do this the result is `['tesla', 'ford', 'bmw', 'audi']`.

Comment: `reverse()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return the reversed list. Do `cars.reverse()` followed by `print(cars)`

Comment: There's a function `reversed(cars)` that returns the reversed list instead of modifying in place.

Comment: What is `reverse_iterator`?

Comment: The question doesn't include code for creating `reverse_iterator` so that part isn't well-formed (letting others reproduce the problem themselves and be certain of their answers). The part that _is_ well-formed is a duplicate.

Comment: Always look at the docs when using functions you haven't played with before!

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

"`s.reverse()` reverses the items of s in place"